# Sort column on number of words per cell from most to least Google script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need to sort a column range on the number of words per cell, from the most words per cell to the least number of words per cell

Example

```
ahtn bmm cnst
Abb Baa
HHH
cc
a
b
c
```

I can sort a column

```
function sortColumn() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lastCol = s.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = s.getLastRow();

  // assumes headers in row 1
  var r = s.getRange(2, 1, lastRow - 1, lastCol);

  // Sort on column G = 7
  r.sort([{ column: 7, ascending: true }]);

}
```

and I can sort an array as I need to

```
function highLow(a,b){
     return b.length - a.length || // sort by length, if equal then
     a.localeCompare(b);    // sort by dictionary order
}
```

which gives

```
[HHH,Abb Baa,cc,ahtn bmm cnst,b,c,a].sort(highLow) =  [ahtn bmm cnst,Abb Baa,HHH,cc,a,b,c]
```

But I can not get how to sort a column range in this fashion as a Google Script, not a formula

Thanks in advance for your assistance

Comment: split on whitespace, sort by array length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to achieve your special sort using the specification which is the same with the method of `sort(sortSpecObj)` in Class Range. For example, when "3" (column C) and "A2:D" is given as a column and a range, the input and output are as follows.

Input :

[image]

Output :

[image]

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? The flow of script is as follows.

1. Retrieve values of the inputted range.
2. Retrieve values of the inputted column from the retrieved values.
3. Sort the column using your script.
4. Retrieve the index of sorted column.
5. Rearrange the values of the sorted range using the index.
6. Put the result values to sheet.

#### Sample script :

```
var sortColumn = "3"; // Column C
var sortRange = "A2:D";

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var values = ss.getRange(sortRange).getValues();
var sorted = values.map(function(e){return e[sortColumn - 1]}).filter(String);
var sortCol = sorted.slice().map(function(e){return [e]});
sorted.sort(function (a,b){return b.length - a.length || a.localeCompare(b)}); // This is your script.
var index = sorted.map(function(e){
  for (var j = 0; j < sortCol.length; j++) {
    if (e == sortCol[j][0] && !sortCol[j][1]) {
      sortCol[j].push("temp");
      return j;
    }
  }
});
var newValues = index.map(function(e){return values[e]});
values.splice(0, sorted.length);
Array.prototype.push.apply(newValues, values);
ss.getRange(sortRange).setValues(newValues);
```

#### Note :

- When you use this sample script, at first, please set `sortColumn` and `sortRange`.
- Please modify this script for your environment.
- If the column you want to sort has some empty cells, please modify `var sorted = values.map(function(e){return e[sortColumn - 1]}).filter(String);` to `var sorted = values.map(function(e){return e[sortColumn - 1]});`.

#### References :

- [sort(sortSpecObj)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#sort(Object))

I worry that I might misunderstand what you want. If this was not what you want, please tell me. I would like to modify this.

Comment: Thank you Tanaike for this, it is exactly what I need

Comment: @xyz I'm glad your issue was solved. I could study from your question. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to be able to sort a Sheet on anything except a column. A simple solution would be to add another column with the word count and sort on that.

A simple word count is described [here](https://www.techjunkie.com/word-count-google-sheets/):

```
=COUNTA(SPLIT(G1, " "))
```

If you want a script then you can read the values from your spreadsheet using range.getValues(), sort the two-dimensional array you get in javascript and then write the sorted values back to the same range:

```
function sortColumn() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lastCol = s.getLastColumn();
  var lastRow = s.getLastRow();

  // assumes headers in row 1
  var r = s.getRange(2, 1, lastRow - 1, lastCol);

  // read the Sheet values into a javascript array
  var values = r.getValues();

  var sortedValues = values.sort(wordCountCompare); 

  // write the sorted values back into the Sheet range
  r.setValues(sortedValues);

}
```

The javascript sort function is quite happy to sort a two-dimensional array, you just have to pass an appropriate compare function so it can figure out the order:

```
function wordCountCompare(a, b) {

  // Sort on column G - in javascript this is array element 6
  // make sure the value is a string (toString)
  // split the string using a space
  // get the length of the split array which is the wordCount
  var wordCountA = a[6].toString().split(" ").length;
  var wordCountB = b[6].toString().split(" ").length;

  return wordCountB - wordCountA;
}
```

Note:
This word count is only approximate and uses spaces to identify a word. You could do a better one that is aware of punctuation marks.